# How do you deal with a No default OpenFlow controller found for default switch?

Tags: controller, switch-statement, default, mininet, openflow

[*** No default OpenFlow controller found for default switch!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfeYA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mininet uses Open vSwitch controller as the default controller, if you omit *--controller* option.
If your system/virtual machine does not have it installed, *mn* command will generate that warning.
Install ovs-controller or just use *--controller=remote* to add external controller, like NOX/POX/ODL.